# React context value with typescript, not able to get the useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state-management

```
export const EmployeeContext = createContext<EmployeesList[] | null>(null);

export const EmployeeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState<EmployeesList[] | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const results = await fetchEmployeeList();
            setEmployeeList(results);
        }
        fetchData()
    }, []);

    return (
        <EmployeeContext.Provider value={[employeeList, setEmployeeList]}>
            {children}
        </EmployeeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Both employeeList and setEmployeeList is throwing an error as "*Type 'EmployeesList[]' is missing the following properties from type 'EmployeesList': userId, jobTitleName, firstName, lastName, and 5 more*"
Even though i have set or as null statement, and i have tried with default object also, still same error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may have been a typo, but your return should be:

```
return (
    <EmployeeContext.Provider value={employeeList}>
        {children}
    </EmployeeContext.Provider>
);
```

If you want to also pass the `setEmployeeList` function, then change your context to the following:

```
type MutableEmployeesList = readonly [EmployeesList[], (employees: EmployeesList[]) => void];
export const EmployeeContext = createContext<MutableEmployeesList>(null);
```

Now the return should be:

```
const mutableEmployeesList = React.useMemo(() => [employeeList, setEmployeeList] as const, [employeeList, setEmployeeList]);

return (
    <EmployeeContext.Provider value={mutableEmployeesList}>
        {children}
    </EmployeeContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: How can we access the set function without passing it

Comment: If we pass like that i am not getting array of employeeList. i am just getting only the object

Comment: @Khirthan, see my edit. Also "_array of employeeList_" is different from "_array of employees_". Your context definition suggests the later; Please be more specific

Comment: @Khirthan are you sure `employeeList` should be of type `EmployeesList[]`, and not just `EmployeesList`?

Comment: the employeeList is actually an array only(EmployeesList[])